# Array inside associative array

Tags: symfony, yaml

I'm trying to achieve a structure like this in a yml:

```
$admin_menu_items = array(
    array(
        "label" => "thisisalabel"
        "sub_menu_items" => array(
             array("label" => "anotherlabel", "route" => "routename"),
             array("label" => "thirdlabel", "route" => "anotherroutename")
        )
    )
);
```

So far i've tried this without success:

```
admin_menu_items:
    - { label: "thisisalabel", sub_menu_items:
        - { label: "anotherlabel", route: "routename" }
        - { label: "thirdlabel", route: "anotherroutename" }
    }
```

Can you guys please help me figuring out the right way for doing this?

Finally i've used a sollution based on Qoop's answers. Here it is:

```
admin_menu_items:
    -
        label: "thisisalabel"
        sub_menu_items:
            - { label: "anotherlabel", route: "routename" }
            - { label: "thirdlabel", route: "anotherroutename" }
```

Comment: I don't understand the language that the first block of code is written in, but it says "array" five times.   I sort of expected, but don't see five ordered lists in the YAML.   Do the 2nd, 4th, and 5th "array"s generate unordered hashes, or ordered lists of key-value pairs?

Comment: Also, if $admin_menu_items represent a variable name rather than the key in a hash table, then the first line may not belong in the YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do it..

```
admin_menu_items:
    -
        label: "thisisalabel"
        sub_menu_items:
            -
                label: "anotherlabel"
                route: "routename"
            -
                label: "thirdlabel"
                route: "anotherroutename"
```

Comment: Finally i've used a sollution similar and based on this.